# How can I align lines to the right except the first in a multiple line equation?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

I have always tried to achieve this but after a few tries decided to skip and concentrate on writing instead of solving it.

I am using `align` environment and trying to align the multiple lined equations to the right except the first line. It is even better if this works with some equation marks are aligned. For example:

```
\begin{align*}
  x &= a + b \\
    + c + d \\ % this line should be aligned to the right
  y &= a + b \\
    + c + d + e % this should be aligned right too
\end{align*} % equals signs should be aligned as well
```

It should look something like this:
[image: right aligned except first]

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  x &= a + b &\\[-1ex]
    & & {} + c + d & \\ % this line should be aligned to the right
  y &= a + b \\[-1ex]
    & & \mathllap{{}+ c + d + e} & % this should be aligned right too
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the usage of the simple command `\hspace{xcm}`. The `\hspace`command when put infront of an equation, pushes it farther towards the right and the shift is basically defined by the user in `cm`. I haven't tried left shifts but I guess negative values within the braces can get the job done.

Additionally, to align the equations, one can use an ampersand to denote the starting point of the alignment

`\begin{align*}
  x =& a + b \\
    &\hspace{1cm}+ c + d \\ % this line should be aligned to the right
  y =& a + b \\
    &\hspace{0.5cm}+ c + d + e % this should be aligned right too
\end{align*} % equals signs should be aligned as well`

The updated code works fine. Give it a try. I'm just too lazy to put the picture again ;)

[image]

Comment: the spacing after the `=` signs is wrong.  either put the `&` before the `=` (as recommended) or put `{}` after each `=` sign.